# Select range in all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select `Range("A1:D30")` in all the worksheets. Yet the code below does not work.

```
Sub selectRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Range("A1:D30").Select
    Next ws      
End Sub
```

Comment: you can't select ranges on different spreadsheets at a same time

Comment: although if you are trying to select the same Range on multiple sheets you may wanna give this a try ; `Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select` and then `Range("A1:D30").Select`

Answer (score 1):

While I usually try and deter the use of `.Select` as a method of accomplishing a goal, in this case the operation may be expedient (although the particulars of the actual operation are lacking).

```
Sub sel_all()
    Dim w As Long, vWSs As Variant

    ReDim vWSs(0 To Worksheets.Count - 1)
    For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        vWSs(w - 1) = Worksheets(w).Name
    Next w

    Worksheets(vWSs).Select
    Worksheets(vWSs(LBound(vWSs))).Activate
    Range("A1:D30").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This is simply amazing! Thanks. ;)